# targeting two divs with a link

Tags: html, css

I want to change `color` of two divs using pure `css`.However I am only able to change `color` of one div using a **`single href`** **`attribute`**.Is it possible using **pure CSS**.

```css
#link1:target{color:red;}
#link2:target{color:green;}
margin-top:20px;
```

```html
<a href="#link1 ">Make links change color</a>
<!-- <a href="#link1 #link2">Make links change color</a> //this not working-->
<div id="link1">
link1
</div>

<div id="link1">
link2
</div>
```

Comment: You should avoid to use `id` as it must be unique in document. Better you go with `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifying your markup, this is the CSS you would use, utilizing the adjacent sibling selector and assuming that's where you wanted the margin. But you can only use an ID on a page once, so you should make the 2nd one `id="link2"`.

```css
#link1:target {
  color: red;
}

#link1:target + #link1 {
  color: green;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#link1 ">Make links change color</a>

<div id="link1">
  link1
</div>

<div id="link1"> <!-- make this one id="link2" -->
  link2
</div>
```

Comment: #link1:target + #link2 {
  color: green;
  margin-top:20px;
}  
<div id="link2"> 
  link2
</div>
We can use different colors also...

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap it in a `div` with the target id.

Like this:

```css
#link1:target {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#link1 ">Make links change color</a>
<div id="link1">
  <div class="link2">
    link1
  </div>

  <div class="link2">
    link2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But i want different colors!